# Using Display Suite how can I remove HTML tags from the teaser?

Tags: display-suite

I'm trying to learn Display Suite and its very powerful.

My teaser summaries contain HTML inside the field and I need to remove that and display only plain text.

How can I do that with Display Suite?

Comment: The HTML will be a result of the 'field' module, not DS.

Comment: I think I understand.

Just for clarification, it isn't possible to create a dynamic field in Display Suite that strips html tags?

Comment: You don't need to. Just go to the teaser display settings for your content type and set the body field output as plain text.

Comment: What he said ^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Thank you!

Update:  I have set the body format to plain text for the teaser display but it appears to be returning the entire body.  Clicking on the cog does not give me to the option to  set the trim length.  Am I missing it?

Comment: Thank you Alex Gill and Alfred Armstrong for the replies!

I was able to use this module to trim and strip html:
http://drupal.org/project/smart_trim